# Instagram search box, how to emulate real typing

Tags: javascript, html, web, instagram

I tried this code:

`input.value = 'a'; input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

but it returns null instead of a list of suggestions.

I expect to find 'a' in the search box with a list of suggestions below.

Comment: Did you try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent?

Comment: x.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'));

returns true

Comment: Sure, it returns true because the function call succeeded. Does it fill the input?

Comment: It doesn't fill the input.

Comment: I think you should check out this link and give us an example we can reproduce, not just little pieces of code https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask